# Why IHTMLDocument2 is not equal to IHTMLDocument2.body.document?

Tags: c#, com-interop, mshtml, ihtmldocument2, iunknown

Why is the following doc2 different from doc22?

```cs
IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Document as IHTMLDocument2;
IHTMLDocument2 doc22 = doc2.body.document as IHTMLDocument2;
bool isequal = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(doc2) == Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(doc22);
//Here, isequal is false. Why?
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the most likely explanation is that different wrapper objects are created for the same thing. Who knows how MSHTML manages this internally. As long as `((pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Document as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IUnknown == (((pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Document as IHTMLDocument2).body.document as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IUnknown` the world is in order ;)